# How to compile Clang with sanitizers

Tags: clang, address-sanitizer

I just [compiled Clang using CMake](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) and then tried running a sanitizer (with `clang -fsanitize=address`), but got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find <CLANG_DIR>/9.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.a:
  No such file or directory
```

I then went to the ["How to build" Address sanitizer page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#how-to-build), but it simply says:

> Build LLVM/Clang with [CMake](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html).

Which takes me back to the first page. The only mention of "sanitize" anywhere within the page is:

> **LLVM_USE_SANITIZER:STRING**
>
> Define the sanitizer used to build LLVM binaries and tests. Possible values are Address, Memory, MemoryWithOrigins, Undefined, Thread, and Address;Undefined. Defaults to empty string.

But this is related to using sanitizers to build LLVM itself, not to making them available after the build.

So, how can I actually build the sanitizers and make them available for Clang?

Answer (score 6):

Runtime library which implements Asan callbacks is in [compiler-rt](https://compiler-rt.llvm.org/) repo so you'll need to build that as well. One easy way to achieve this is to clone `compiler-rt` to `llvm/projects` before running cmake.

Comment: Is it something like this ```cmake -GNinja -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt" source-to-llvm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release``` ?

Comment: Yes, your command will work if all three repos are in same folder, side-by-side. If you cloned `clang` and `compiler-rt` repos into `llvm/tools/clang` and `llvm/projects/compiler-rt` repo (as explained in ) you can do just `cmake -GNinja source-to-llvm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`.